# How to verify SSL Enablement in Netezza Database using a query in client tool like DBVISUALIZER?

Tags: database, netezza, dbvisualizer

I am trying to check or verify SSL is enabled or not for my current Netezza connection.

I have tried multiple queries, but none of the them is working.

Below are some listed queries, which I tried in DBVISUALIZER:-

```
SELECT * FROM _v_system_ssl_config;

SELECT dbname, use_ssl FROM _v_database;

SELECT ssl_enabled FROM _v_system_info;

SELECT ssl_enabled, ssl_certificate, ssl_cipher FROM _v_system_info;

SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'ssl';

SELECT setting FROM _v_system_settings WHERE name='SSL';
```

Please help me with at-least one working query in Netezza to verify SSL Enablement for particular connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify it in two ways

1. By looking at the postgressql.conf file and checking if the database is configured to use SSl certificates or not. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=security-configuring-ssl-certificate
2. Connect to the database using nzsql client. If SSL is configured it will confirm it.

> nz@netezza01 ?]$ nzsql -u admin -p <password>
>
> Welcome to nzsql, the IBM Netezza SQL interactive terminal.
>
> Type: \h for help with SQL commands  ? for help on internal slash
> commands  \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query  \q to quit
>
> SSL enabled connection. Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, protocol: TLSv1.2

Comment: I know these steps you mentioned above. I need a query or command that will work in client tool like DBVISUALIZER. I need to verify it from client end.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "show connection"? It tells you which clients/Ips are allowed to connect using ssl/normal connection.

CONNID | CONNTYPE | CONNDB | CONNIPADDR |   CONNIPMASK    | CONNAUTH
--------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------+----------
1 | local    | all    |            |                 | trust
2 | hostssl  | all    | 127.0.0.1  | 255.255.255.255 | md5
3 | hostssl  | all    | 0.0.0.0    | 0.0.0.0         | md5